# In SQL Server, does the performance increase if I include fewer rows for an index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, include

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, I did not know how to type the question so google would find an answer.

Let's say I have a table `T` with 10 columns (`a,b,c...j`).

I have a query that counts c, sums d, sums when f=1 e, sums f where a=22 and b between (day x, day y).

The index used by SQL Server is nonclustered index `name_ab` on `T (a, b) include (c, d, e, f)`

Would the performance decrease if I have a nonclustered index `name_ab2` on `T (a, b) include (c...j)`?

The reason I'm asking is because I have a lot of reports with very different queries on huge tables and I would prefer not to make an index for each query 
but to have an index for the whole table

Thank you

Comment: Just having *one* index with **all** the columns included **DOES NOT** speed up any possible query! Quite the contrary...... so if you have lots of reports, you'll have to carefully analyze **exactly what** requirements they have, and then find the best indices - one index with every columns will *most likely* **NOT** help in most cases!

Comment: what version is your sql server, if it's 2012 plus, you can use columnar index, which inc all columns (except some data types), and is very good for this kind of analysis (aggregation, reporting).

Comment: For marc_s, my index are only on column a and column b, unless i misunderstood : msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx it shouldnt index those other column For thotwielder, sql server 2012 and thank you, ill look into it

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your sql version I highly recommend using SQL's database engine tuning advisor to help with determine good indexes for the queries that hit the table.

Typically as other half already mentioned, it is not wise to over index but instead sample a few additional indexes and determine the overall increase. A secondary concern is having indexes on large tables with lower fill factors eats up a lot of disk space as well so it might be something to take into account.

I personally setup my larger tables (larger then 1tb in a single table - all transactional) with partitioning by month. I set a new partition each month so query's with dates in the where clause only hit the corresponding partitions that are required per month.

Just some food for thought.

Comment: ill look into the tuning advisor and the partition.
But again, my question is on the include not the index.
What happens with performance if the number of index stays the same but the number of include changes?

Answer (score 0):

after much research.
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Category_iddate_1
ON [Item] (id,date)
INCLUDE (a,b)
GO
and 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Category_iddate_2
ON [Item] (id,date)
INCLUDE (a,b,c,d)
GO
the difference is that if abcd is all my column, then that index is equivalent to a clustered index.
CLustered index are good if you dont insert and delete alot
I hope this helps
Have a good day